# How to do input validation for MaskedTextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to check the input for the date `MaskedTextField`. I have searched but only found a solution if I use `TextFormField` (using validator parameter).

My current code set the input to automatically set pattern of `XXXX-XX-XX` (year-month-day), but for month and day, user can input any number like (1994-88-45), which is not practical (88 is not a correct value for a month and 45 is not a correct value of day).

```
     MaskedTextField(
                  maskedTextFieldController: controllerDOB,
                  mask: "xxxx-xx-xx",
                  maxLength: 10,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  inputDecoration:
                      new InputDecoration(hintText: "0000-00-00"),
                ),
```